# How to extract text that is wrapped in \t and \n in selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to extract some text from an element and print it in console, however, the text is wrapped in \n and \t *as gathered from this JSON file during a GET request*. The HTML format looks like this:

`<span class="classname ">\n\t\t\t\n \n HELLO\n \n\n`

and in the inspect element xpath it look like so (image because I cannot replicate the formatting here):
[image: formatting in html]

I have tried to use `s.replace("\n\t" , "")` , `s.strip()` , and `s.translate({ord(c): None for c in string.whitespace})` all which just printed a blank ( ) in console. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would assume that `s.strip()` should do the work.

Comment: if you want to use replace: `s.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '')` because it replaces strict sequences (also can use in one line like this since `.replace` returns the replaced string)

Comment: or maybe `s.remove('\n').remove('\t')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I have a string like this :

```
s = '\n\t\t\t\n \n HELLO\n \n\n'
```

I would use the below regex :

```
\n|\t\|
```

and using `replace` then followed by `.strip()` ,I would do this :

```
s = '\n\t\t\t\n \n HELLO\n \n\n'

a = s.replace("\n|\t\| ", ' ').strip()
print(a)
```

**output :**

> HELLO
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
s.xpath('normalize-space(//span[@class="classname "]/text())')
```