# How do I retrieve text from a text node in Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So, essentially I want to get the text from the site and print it onto console.
This is the HTML snippet:

```
<div class="inc-vat">
   <p class="price">
        <span class="smaller currency-symbol">£</span>
        1,500.00
        <span class="vat-text">&nbsp;inc. vat</span>    
   </p>
</div>
```

Here is an image of the DOM properties:
[image]

How would I go abouts retrieving the '1,500.00'? I have tried to use `self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/text()')` but that throws an error which says ***The result of the xpath expression is: [object Text]. It should be an element.*** I have also used other methods like `.text` but they either only print the '£' symbol, print a blank or throw the same error.

Comment: Try this - `browser.find_element_by_xpath("xpath for <p>").get_attribute("innerText")`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68778959/how-to-extract-text-that-is-wrapped-in-t-and-n-in-selenium

Comment: see the above link, did that resolve your issue ?

Comment: @cruisepandey the answer that pmadhu provided was the solution.

Comment: @noobcode0000 : You need to learn to accept the answer which help you solve your problem, I yesterday gave you one solution for that you have not acknowledge me.  see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68778959/how-to-extract-text-that-is-wrapped-in-t-and-n-in-selenium

Comment: @noobcode0000 : also if there are multiple answer, you should choose the best answer which actually solve the question and is optimal. I hope you'll learn more from this community.

Comment: @cruisepandey your answer was helpful but that was for a different problem I was having, so i'll mark your answer as the solution on the last post. It was my bad for not marking it.

Comment: @noobcode0000 : not an issue, you are always welcome to create new tickets. we don't mind that, we actually encourage folks to do that. Also I believe pmadhu comment will fetch you all the details like `£ 1,500.00 ;inc. vat`, so that's why I have given you solution below, you can try that out and it shall fetch you 1500.00. do let me know if you have any concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below css :

```
p.price
```

sample code :-

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("p.price").text.split(' ')[1]
print(elem)
```